# How to typecast in c# with T type and access its property and variables

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, generics, polymorphism

IDE: C# .net, Winforms

Before I begin pleas have a look on situation:

```
 public class ParentClass
{

}


public class A : ParentClass
{
    public int A_item1;
    public string A_item2;
    public int CommonVariable;
}

public class B : ParentClass
{
    public int B_item1;
    public string B_item2;
    public int CommonVariable;
}
```

now I have form1.cs from where I am using it

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ParentClass> lstA = new List<ParentClass>();
        lstA.Add(new A());
        lstA.Add(new A());

        List<ParentClass> lstB = new List<ParentClass>();
        lstA.Add(new B());
        lstA.Add(new B());

        lstA = AssignValue<A>(lstA);

        lstB = AssignValue<B>(lstB);



    }

    private List<ParentClass> AssignValue<T>(List<ParentClass> lstParent)
    {
        foreach (var item in lstParent)
        {
            (item as T).CommonProperty = 5;  // can you tell me how to dynamically type cast here, what ever type is supplied it will type cast accordingly..
        }
        return lstParent;

    }
```

As you can see I have created 2 child classes A, B and one ParentClass,

In form1.cs I have create 2 List of type Parentclass and adding a type object in list 1 and B type objects in list 2, and passing it to a function AssignValues

Here I want to type caste it automatically, whatever user supply the type T, can you tell me how to achieve this.

Please don't suggest me to move this variable in parentClass, because in my project I can't modify parent class, also I don't want to solve this with switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still confused, but what I have get in the example, you can use dynamic(C# 4.0) like this-

```
private List<ParentClass> AssignValue<T>(List<ParentClass> lstParent)
    {
        foreach (var item in lstParent)
        {
            dynamic objData = Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
            if (objData != null)
            {
                //This call would throw exception if CommonProperty is not member of the T Class
                objData.CommonProperty = 5;
            }
        }
        return lstParent;

    }
```

If this is not the case you want, please elaborate more whats the problem you are facing

Comment: Downvoted for using dynamic when proper, compile-time solution exists.

Comment: I personally don't think that's a reason for downvoting. You may not like dynamic (neither do I if it's unnecessary) , but it's perfectly valid and also a correct answer to the problem. IMO downvoting should reflect the invalidity of the answer, not your personal view of how language features should be used.

Comment: simple and useful solution.

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni despite what I said above, I meant that *just* for the downvoting of the answer. I personally like the other two answers (Euphoric 's or Lasse's ) better than this and think they are more correct than using `dynamic` in this case

Comment: @Jcl ya those are better, if this(Dynamic) feature is not available in c#, for other programming language such as c++ these 2 are correct, any way, If I use other two answers than I need to inherit my all classes around 30 classes, with interface, but with "Rohit Prakash" answer saved inherit effort, and worked.

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni investing time and effort in solving bad design decisions usually ends up paying higher (in the long run) than "patching" over it. But it's your decision of course

Answer (score 5):

Create a new interface:

```
public interface IHasCommonProperty
{
    int CommonProperty {get; set;}
}

public class A : ParentClass, IHasCommonProperty
{
    public int A_item1;
    public string A_item2;
    public int CommonProperty {get ; set; }
}

public class B : ParentClass, IHasCommonProperty
{
    public int B_item1;
    public string B_item2;
    public int CommonProperty {get ; set; }
}  

private List<ParentClass> AssignValue(List<ParentClass> lstParent)
{
    foreach (var item in lstParent)
    {
        var commonInterface = item as IHasCommonProperty;
        if (commonInterface != null)
            commonInterface.CommonProperty = 5;
    }
    return lstParent;
}
```

Comment: yea, its a new way, using interface, so there is no way in c# to typecasting with T type.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is make the compiler aware of how your classes are laid out.

Basically you have to tell it, "this `T` type, here's what I know about it".

Since there is nothing common between the two, except for two properties that have the same name and type, the compiler won't let you do this easily. Note that two properties that have the same name, and type, but are in different types, are different properties, there's nothing common you can cast this to that will allow you to access them.

Except for `dynamic` that is, and there's already another answer here about that, but let's find a better way.

What you have to do is move the common property down into your common base class:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public int CommonVariable;
}


public class A : ParentClass
{
    public int A_item1;
    public string A_item2;
}

public class B : ParentClass
{
    public int B_item1;
    public string B_item2;
}
```

Then you have to tell the generic method that all types it will be given as `T` will at least be that common base class:

```
private List<ParentClass> AssignValue<T>(List<ParentClass> lstParent)
    where T : ParentClass
```

See that `where T : ParentClass` clause I added above, this tells the compiler that each type is of that type, and now the code can be written like this:

```
{
    foreach (var item in lstParent)
        item.CommonVariable = 5;
    return lstParent;
}
```

---

Now, having said all that I question the validity of this method.

As it stands now, you don't actually *need* it to be generic. If you move the common field down into the base class, you can just write the method like this:

```
private List<ParentClass> AssignValue(List<ParentClass> lstParent)
{
    foreach (var item in lstParent)
        item.CommonVariable = 5;
    return lstParent;
}
```

---

If you can't, or won't, move the common field down into a base class you can do it another way, with interfaces.

First make the field into a property, then declare an interface exposing this property and implement that property on each class, then let the method, which still doesn't have to be generic, take that interface:

```
public class ParentClass
{
}

public interface ICommon
{
    int CommonVariable { get; set; }
}

public class A : ParentClass : ICommon
{
    public int A_item1;
    public string A_item2;
    public int CommonVariable { get; set; }
}

public class B : ParentClass : ICommon
{
    public int B_item1;
    public string B_item2;
    public int CommonVariable { get; set; }
}  

private List<ICommon> AssignValue(List<ICommon> lstParent)
{
    foreach (var item in lstParent)
        item.CommonVariable = 5;
    return lstParent;
}
```